# c# ajax post 400 bad request firefox only

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, wcf, firefox

I am trying to write an ajax application using C# backend. For ajax calls I am using jquery. It works fine with IE and Google Chrome but it gives 400 bad request when I try to open it using Firefox. Here is the front end code

```
$.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:25028/Service.svc/Fun",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        timeout: 10000,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify({input: 'input'}),
        crossDomain: true,
        success: function (input) {
            var data = JSON.parse(input);
            alert(data.data);
        },
        error: function (input, textstatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(textstatus);
        }
    });
```

And I am using the following bindings in web.config if they are relevant.

```
    <behavior name="EndpBehavior">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>


  <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="Service">
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Service" behaviorConfiguration="EndpBehavior"/>
  </service>
```

The function definition is as follows

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "*", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public string Fun( string input )
{
    return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new { data = "this is data" });
}
```

}

I don't understand what the mistake is.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use fiddler or wireshark to find out the difference.

Comment: Try clearing `cache:false`.

Comment: If you open Firebug, what does it show as the request?

Comment: Firebug tells 400 bad request When I click on that it shows the following messages
Accept text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Access-Control-Request-He... content-type
Access-Control-Request-Me... POST
Cache-Control no-cache
Connection keep-alive
Host localhost:25028
Origin http://localhost:25121
Pragma no-cache
User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0

Comment: I just wanted you to check what it specifically shows under the 'Request' section - I mean is it showing anything in 'data'?

Comment: It doesn't have any field like 'data'

Comment: @AdityaAnirudhT - curious to know if any of the answers worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use fiddler. http://fiddler2.com. Also use BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare and Method = "POST"

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding the following line in your service implementation, before you return the Json:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with");
```

After this, clear the Firefox session/cookies (or even better, open FF in 'Private browsing mode') - and hit the url again.